# Sklearn n_jobs parameter is not affecting number of cores used

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I'm trying to do feature selection with the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd')

sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(model, n_features_to_select=3, direction='forward', n_jobs=-2, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')

sfs.fit(X, y)
```

where X is of shape (213661, 354)

However, no matter what I set the `n_jobs` parameter, it appears that sklearn is never using more than 1 thread for the computation. This is immediately apparent when I run the terminal command `htop`. Screenshot below shows output of `htop` during the above `SequentialFeatureSelector` run (this is a shared server, so others are also using RAM).

[htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNxO9.png)

I'm running a Linux machine with 80 threads (2 threads per core, 20 cores per socket, 2 sockets). Changing n_jobs as marginal effect on runtime as the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd')

for j in [-2, 20, 40]:
    start = time.time()
    sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(model, n_features_to_select=3, direction='forward', n_jobs=j,    cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
    sfs.fit(X, y)
    stop = time.time()
    print(stop-start)
```

yields the following output:

```
341.53
289.15
303.93
```

It appears that all threads are available, as seen from this command:

```
import multiprocessing
n_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(n_cpus)
```

Outputs `80`

Additionally, packages like polars successfully utilize parallelization in the same jupyter notebook.

I know sklearn leverages joblib for parallelization, so I tried to run some tests on the joblib backend:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from math import sqrt
import time
for j in [-1, -2, 1, 10, 20, 40]:
    start = time.time()
    Parallel(n_jobs=j)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(400000))
    stop = time.time()
    print(stop-start)
```

yielded results

```
73.6
4.9
133.8
11.8
20.5
37.8
```

Which indicates that joblib is working correctly? (ignoring the increase from 10 to 40, which maybe due to parallelization overhead costing more than the computation itself)

Why are the `n_jobs` parameter inputs not being reflected in the `htop` output, nor affecting the runtime? Am I missing something, or is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 1):

`n_jobs` is only used for cross validation, you only have `cv=3` which means only 3 classifiers can be trained concurrently, hence only 3 cores are fully used as seen in your `htop` screenshot, the rest of the logic is sequential, and doesn't get parallelized.

To utilize more cores you have to do more work.

1. increasing the `cv` splits
2. you could train another `model` of different classifier in a different thread
3. that other classifier like `SVC` can have a hyperameter that you can do a `GridSearchCV` for, in parallel.

Your example just does too little work to use the extra cores.

Comment: Is there a way to improve core utilization in the described scenario of the OP?

Comment: @Björn not without increasing the "work", i have added some examples.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks for the the thoughtful answer, that's very helpful. If you don't mind a follow-up question, do you know why the CPU% for the process is at 100 instead of 300? I would expect it to be 300 if it's running 3 threads.

Comment: @csmittie because the other workers are in a different process, you should find 4 processes named `python` of which 3 are doing work at 100%, python natively only consumes 100% per process due to the GIL, so it spawns more processes to use more CPUs.